# VLC - Unable to open MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'

Tags: webcam, vlc, cvlc

I have been trying to stream live webcam footage from my PS3 eye toy (connected to RPI through USB).

I downloaded VLC and ran:

```
 vlc 4l2:///dev/video0
```

But I keep running into the error

```
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'
```

I even tried `video1` but still got the same error

Any ideas?

Comment: To rule out the obvious are you sure the camera is /dev/video0? Who owns the device and what permsiions does the device have?

Comment: check this out: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Command_Line_Examples/

Answer (score 3):

Your user doesn't have permissions to open /dev/video because that dev file is owned by root user and video group. You need to add your user to the video group.

```
usermod -aG video ${USER}
```

The `a` is important as otherwise `${USER}` will be *removed* from all other groups the user is already in (see `man usermod`).  This includes `sudo` if `${USER}` is `pi`.

Added group memberships aren't effective until the user next logs in.

Comment: Should be `usermod -aG` as `If the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current supplementary group list.`

Answer (score 1):

As per [this answer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=257741) from the archlinux forums, it seems that vlc may require the [zvbi](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/zvbi/) package to be able to open v4l2 devices. Indeed, installing it solved the problem for me.